# Function on objects that return specific values when the object is cast

Tags: php, oop, object

First of all, I apologize that this question is so vague.  I can't remember what this is called, or how they work, so it's very difficult to start searching or formulate a good title.

I have two questions wrapped into one:

### First:

How are objects converted to other types internally?  What is this called?

Example:

```
$Obj{
    $value = 1;
    $other = 2;
    $more = 3;
}

$myObj = (string)$Obj;

print $myObj; // prints "1, 2, 3" or something like that
```

### Second:

Can this method be used in math?  Is there some override function that recognizes when an Object is being used in math?

Example:

```
$Obj{
        $value = 1;
        $other = 2;
        $more = 3;
    }

$result = 4 / $Obj;

print $result; // prints ".66666667" or something similar (sum of all properties)
```

## Update:

I think it might have something to do with [serialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), but I know I've heard of a case where this is done "automatically" without having to call `serialize()` **and** it's done in a way that doesn't actually serialize the whole object, it just converts it to a useable value, like my above examples.

## Final:

Thanks for @trey for being right about it being [**casting**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) and to @webbiedave for pointing me to the magic method [__toString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **casting** as you can define the magic method [__toString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) to allow the object to be cast to a string as desired, which will then allow PHP to cast it to an int or float in math.

Take the following example:

```
class A
{
    public $value = 1;
    public $other = 2;
    public $more  = 3;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string)($this->value + $this->other + $this->more);
    }
}

$obj = new A();
echo 4 / (string)$obj; // outputs 0.66666666666667
```

Comment: So I assume it's best practice to actually return a string, given the name, but can `__toString()` return theoretically anything?  Is there a more generic function that allows you to catch any cast?

Comment: You must return a string or it will cause a fatal error. PHP does not offer other types of magic cast methods.

Comment: I was late, good info, I won't keep looking for other magic methods;)

Answer (score 3):

It's called type casting when you change an object to a different data type, as for the second part, I'm not entirely sure I understand you, are you trying to type cast during a math function?

it sounds like this may be more along the lines of what you're looking for:

```
class User
{
  public $first_name='John';
  public $last_name='Smith';

  public function __toString()
  {
    return "User [first='$this->first_name', last='$this->last_name']";
  }
}
 $user=new User;
 print '<span>'.$user.'</span>';
```

but I'm unable to find documentation about how to make this work when the object is converted to an interger... I'll update if I do

Comment: No, not typecasting.  There's a special property of Objects that allows them to return a value that makes sense when they are used in this way.  If you just typecast an Object without this special override, it will either return an error or a result that's unhelpful (like: `(string)$Obj == Object(5)` or something).

Comment: hmmm type juggling is the closest thing I can think of to what your asking about as far as the internal conversion goes, let me see what I can figure out about the special operation

Comment: thanks for your help.  It looks like you were right about casting.  I could have sworn there was a way without manually casting it to (string) :)  I'm going to give @webbiedave the answer, but you were certainly helpful, and I appreciate the time spent!  **edit:**  I imagine integer casting would just be `parseInt((string)$Obj);`.  On the other hand, php is loosely typed, so if `__toString` is returning even a "kind-of" number it would probably work without the explicit parse :)